# How to change CSS property before element is created?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to modify the div's css before the `window.onload`, and `body.onload`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
            }
            div {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
        <script>
            HTMLDivElement.prototype.style.marginTop = (window.innerHeight/2 - HTMLDivElement.scaleHeight/2) + "px";
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
        foo<br/>bar
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't change a DOM element's style properties before they're loaded. Why don't you just use css?

Comment: To vertically center the element, why not just use display:table-cell and vertical-align:middle?

Comment: I think this is a valid question, there are instances when a user only has access to change a javascript file and not the HTML or CSS files of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if that works in all browsers but you could append a new `style`-node inside your `head` section like this:

```
var marginTop = ...;
var node = document.createElement("style");
node.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
node.innerHTML = "div { margin-top: " + marginTop + "px; }";
document.head.appendChild(node);
```

Your `head` element must obviously exist for this to work.
I know it's ugly and I can't recommend using this but I think it's what you wanted.

UPDATE:
I found another way, which in my opinion is better because of the API you can use:

```
// insert a stylesheet if you don't have one
if (document.styleSheets.length == 0) {
    document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style"));
}

var marginTop = ...;
var rule = "div { margin-top: " + marginTop + "px; }";
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(rule);
```

For more information you may visit http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html
Again I don't know if all browsers support this.

Answer (score 0):

Before window on load, the document isnt loaded into the dom.

So from memory.. javascript cant edit it.

You could always just edit it after onLoad and shouldn't notice much different.

So for example in jQuery:

```
<script>
(function () {
    var divHeight = ($('div').height())/2,
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight/2;

    $('div').css('margin-top', windowHeight - divHeight);
}())
</script>
```

Comment: Sure, but the question doesn't mention jQuery anywhere.

Comment: I edited the my answer to mention jquery. Considering that the question cant be solved in javascript, a random example that could solve there problem in jquery isnt out of line.

Comment: "Can't be solved in JavaScript?" What jQuery is then, magic pixie dust?

Comment: "Can't be solved in JavaScript?" - within the context of the question (before onload). "What jQuery is then, magic pixie dust?" - yep, you should try it out

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript. If you can do it in jQuery, you can do it in plain JS.

Comment: Obviously... Give it a rest, it was a basic example of a different solution (after onload), not the exact solution to the posters problem.

Answer (score 0):

when element is not loaded, how you will be able find it. this must be done on the server side.

BTW why you need this kind of functionality?

Comment: I just want to vertically center the div

Comment: If you don't have to consider older browsers you could achieve vertical alignment with a flexbox: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/