# Change CSS before element loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, cookies

Aim: I have a main navbar that opens when clicked (using jquery and the css style `--active`). If the user leaves it open and navigates to a new page on the site, the navbar needs to stay open without first appearing to be closed.

Problem: The navbar does stay open (using a cookie to remember its state), but is briefly seen in the default style (ie closed) before adopting the `--active` class. Looks very clunky, like a quick flash.

Can anyone come up with a way to get the navbar to remember its state from page to page AND (when cookie is 'opened') adopt the `--active` class styles without briefly showing the default ones?

(I've had a look at [How to change CSS property before element is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070055/how-to-change-css-property-before-element-is-created), but it's not working for me).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const menuButton = $('.header__menu-button');
  const menuState = Cookies.get('menuState');

  if (menuState == 'opened') {
    menuButton.addClass('--active');
  };

  menuButton.on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('--active');

    if (menuButton.hasClass('--active')) {
      Cookies.set('menuState', 'opened');
    } else {
      Cookies.set('menuState', 'closed');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}

.header {
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #add8e6;
}

.header__button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.header__menu-button {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.menuTransition {
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.header__menu-button.--active {
  min-width: 250px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__button-container">
    <button class="header__menu-button menuTransition"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `The navbar does stay open, but is briefly seen in the default style (ie closed) before adopting the --active class. Looks very clunky, like a quick flash.` There is absolutely nothing you can do about that. The page will be loaded in its default state until the DOM is ready and your JS runs to open the navbar again. The only fixes for this is to read the cookie state on the server and open the navbar there, or change your site to use the Single Page Application pattern, but this is not a quick-fix. It will require re-architecting the entire site structure from the ground up.

Comment: You would need to read the cookie with server side code and apply the class that way (when you build the page) if you want there to be no "flash" - otherwise js will always wait until the dom has loaded the element before it is affected

Comment: If you can’t do this on the server side, then you can only try and make this happen earlier on the client side: Move the class that makes the menu show as open further up the DOM tree to the `html` element (use it in CSS rules that make appropriate use of descendant selectors to format the menu and the button accordingly), and take the JS code out of `document.ready`, and make it apply as soon as possible instead.

Answer (score -1):

If in new page menu was `--active` use this code before `$(document).ready(function()`

```
$("button.header__menu-button").removeClass("--active");
```

This code remove `--active` class from your navbar! Before you see page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button.header__menu-button").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("--active");
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}

.header {
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #add8e6;
}

.header__button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.header__menu-button {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.menuTransition {
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.header__menu-button.--active {
  min-width: 250px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header">
  <div class="header__button-container">
    <button class="header__menu-button menuTransition"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to have completely misunderstood the problem, and why this will not work.

Comment: Why did you change my answer !!!   i said use this code   $("button.header__menu-button").removeClass("--active"); before $(document).ready(function() !!!

Comment: I fixed the formatting and grammar. I would suggest you do this accurately yourself from now on to avoid unclear answers. Also note that calling any operation *before* document.ready fires *will not work*. Regardless of any errors, this answer is still irrelevant to the problem. I would suggest deleting it.